Nodejs Lambda function to update a PDF using pdf-lib or pdfkit
I have a NodeJs lambda function and I am trying to update a small one page PDF file from S3 bucket and save it on a different S3 bucket.
I saw the samples of pdf-lib library, but they seem to be outdated.
https://pdf-lib.js.org/#examples
All my PDF files are small and size is not a concern.
Here is what I have. However, it doesn't update the pdf file. Instead, it creates a new blank file and sets name and address.
    const inputFile = await s3.send(new GetObjectCommand(getObjectParams));
    const inputBuffer = await streamToBuffer(inputFile.Body);
    const name = 'John Doe';
    const address = '123 Main St, City, Country';
    const modifiedPdfBuffer = await modifyPDF(inputBuffer, name, address);

async function modifyPDF(inputBuffer, name, address) {
    // Load the existing PDF using pdf-lib
    const pdfDoc = await PDFLibDocument.load(inputBuffer);
    const doc = new PDFDocument({
      autoFirstPage: false,
    });
  
    // Collect the output in memory
    const buffers = [];
    doc.on('data', buffers.push.bind(buffers));

    // Embed the existing PDF in the PDFKit document
    const pages = pdfDoc.getPages();
    for (const page of pages) {
      const { width, height } = page.getSize();
      doc.addPage({ size: [width, height] });  
      doc.fontSize(12).text(name, 100, 150);
      doc.fontSize(12).text(address, 100, 170);
    }  
    // Finalize the PDF file
    doc.end();
  
    // Convert the collected chunks into a single Buffer
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        doc.on('end', () => {
            const pdfBuffer = Buffer.concat(buffers);
            resolve(pdfBuffer);
        });    
        doc.on('error', reject);
      });    
  }

